# eslint doesnt detect deconstruct variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, linter

I have the following code:

```js
    for ([uri, { socket, settings }] of map) {

        // parse websocket urls
        let url1 = new url.URL(ws.url);
        let url2 = new url.URL(uri);

        // override http(s) with ws(s)
        url2.protocol = url1.protocol;

        console.log(`Bridge "%s" <-> ${socket}://${host}:${port}`, url2);

        bridge(url2, settings, socket);

    }
```

which deconstruct variables, but eslint does not detect the variables:

```
/home/.../handler.js
  81:11  error  'uri' is not defined       no-undef
  81:18  error  'socket' is not defined    no-undef
  81:26  error  'settings' is not defined  no-undef
  85:32  error  'uri' is not defined       no-undef
  90:40  error  'socket' is not defined    no-undef
  90:52  error  'host' is not defined      no-undef
  90:60  error  'port' is not defined      no-undef
  92:22  error  'settings' is not defined  no-undef
  92:32  error  'socket' is not defined    no-undef

✖ 9 problems (9 errors, 0 warnings)
```

How can i tell the linter that its fine and the variables are detect properly?

*.eslintrc.json*

```json
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "ignorePatterns": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double",
            {
                "avoidEscape": true, // Does not work https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes#avoidescape
                "allowTemplateLiterals": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You *did* not define them. Add `const` to declare them (instead of having assignments to implicit globals)

Comment: @Bergi What a stupid mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for of loop requires const, **for(const**

```
const map = [
  [
    "uri",
    {
      socket: "",
      settings: ''
    },
  ],
];

for (const [uri, { socket, settings }] of map) {
    console.log(uri, socket, settings);
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't *require* it, but it certainly would be a good practice